# How to control spacing in header text?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, spacing

is it possible to apply spacing to overall header text, and have a special header not to have long spacing. its very hard to explain so the codes below:

got:

```
Support       30       FREE       Tips       Guest001
```

need:

```
Support       30 FREE Tips       Guest001
```

code here:

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
  }
    p.space { /* header space lenght */
    word-spacing: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="space">
<a href="support.htm">Support</a> 
30 FREE Tips
Guest001</p>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question :(

Comment: can you explain more? got: Support 30 FREE Tips Guest001 need: Support 30 FREE Tips Guest001 looks same to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `span` to text

```
<span>30 FREE Tips</span>
```

Then add `word-spacing` as 0px

```
p span{ word-spacing: 0px;}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #6B6B6B;
}
p.space { 
  word-spacing: 50px;
}
p span{ 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p class="space">
  <a href="support.htm">Support</a> 
  <span>30 FREE Tips</span>
  Guest001
</p>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @Stew?